# MVC encodig strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I set the ValidateInputAttribute in my controller action to false. In my view, i have a textbox:

```
<p>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name.LastName, new { maxlength = "100" })%> 
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name.LastName) %>
    <%= Html.Hidden("hiddenLastName", Model.Name.LastName) %>
</p>
```

Now i can save everything thourgh that textbox, but when displaying data i see strange characters. So when i save `<script>alert(“Boo!”)</script>` and open the site again to see the result, i see: <script>alert(“Boo!”)</script>

How can i fix this?

Note: i'm not encoding the input somewhere else in my code.

Comment: You save `<script>alert(“Boo!”)</script>` and then you see `<script>alert(“Boo!”)</script>`, what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to put it here, i see strange characters like &lt , &g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see `<` instead of `&lt;`, use
[HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx)

If you're saving user input in a database and want them to allow entering html, encode their input in your **controler** before storing in a database:

```
model.Input = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(model.Input);
```

And when you want to dispaly that input, Decode in in your **view**:

```
@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(model.Input)
```

And instead of setting ValidateInputAttribute to false, use [AllowHtml] attribute for Input property in your **model**:

```
[Required]
[AllowHtml]
public string Input {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's encoded String. If script tag can attack your site, so this string that is converted to Html encoded string is safe. but if you want to display un-encoded string with tag element, use HtmlString.

```
HtmlString htmlString = new HtmlString("rawString"); 
String encodedString = htmlString.ToHtmlString();
String not_encodedString = htmlString.ToString();
```

here is msdn link : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring.aspx

Comment: Or just [Html.Raw()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.98).aspx)